# Adding a menu to the navigation based on customer tag

Tags: shopify, liquid

we are using the Stiletto Shopify-theme, and from header.liquid it is rendering the menu like so:

{% render 'navigation' with menu: links, blocks: section.blocks %}

This again points to navigation.liquid and then navigation-submenu.liquid.

How can I go about to add another menu to appear at the end of this one?

Currently our menu looks like Menu 1 | Menu 2 | Menu 3 | Menu 4, and I would like to include Menu 5 after these other menu items, based on a customer tag being present or not.

I tried to use {% render 'other-menu' with menu: links, blocks: section.blocks %} under {% render 'navigation' with menu: links, blocks: section.blocks %} , but that didn't work.

I have figured out that I can assign menu based on customer tag, and it replaces the entire menu, but that would entail changing both menus everytime something changes. Is is possible to just have two separate menus, our main menu with the second menu added after it if the tag is true or not?